# How to restore wp-usermeta table in phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I was working on wp-usermeta and unintentionally set all the meta_keys to "user_phone" and all the meta_values to null, i dont have a backup and if I had it I don't know where is it. please help me :'( Also I can't log in to my wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to restore without a backup. Your only option is to delete all users (including meta data) outside of WordPress admin (edit the database or WP-CLI), and re-create the users.

Comment: I just realized I have a wordpress page copy, but I don't know if there is a copy of the database, do you know something about it?

Comment: What do you mean by "WordPress page copy"?